# Reading out the day of the week via Date () for local notifications in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uilocalnotification

I am trying to send a certain message with local notifications and that depends on the day of the week, now my code has to know what day of the week it is in order to send the notification.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want this (or kind of, for another date)

```
if let weekDay = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday], from: Date()).weekday {
   // do this what's needed
}
```

Comment: Should the last part be .weekday rather than .day?

Comment: @Subha_26, you're right. This is will return nil since only the `.weekday` component was requested, but the `.date` component returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a single component (the day of the week in our case) of the current date like this:

```
if Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date()) == 1 {
    // Yay, it's Sunday!
}
```

From the docs: "The weekday units are the numbers 1 through N (where for the Gregorian calendar N=7 and 1 is Sunday)."

Comment: Ok, but could I also trigger the notification with UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger trigger. or something like this?

Comment: Your initial question is not very clear, but `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` takes a time interval. I'm assuming you want to trigger a notification on an upcoming weekday. `Calendar` and `DateComponents` help you compute that interval.

Comment: Something like this would set a trigger for next Sunday at 10am:
```let nextDate = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: DateComponents(hour: 10, weekday: 1), matchingPolicy: .nextTime);
let interval = nextDate?.timeIntervalSinceNow; let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval, repeats: false)
```

Comment: Yes, that’s what I want.